# Tkinter GUI crashes after one button pressed with Py3

Tags: python, tkinter

I've made a code that calls a script for each button pressed basically and for now it seems to crash after one button pressed. In background the CMD gives me the correct output of the script called but I cannot continue to use the GUI since it is freeze with the first button pressed.

Do you know who to continue to use TKinter even after one action was completed?

Sample code:

```
import subprocess
import tkinter as tk
import os
from typing import List
    
root= tk.Tk() 

canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width = 350, height = 350) 
canvas1.pack()

def start_shell(): 
       subprocess.call([r'[path]\commands\adb_shell.bat'])
           
button1 = tk.Button (root, text='Start shell',command=start_shell,)
canvas1.create_window(170, 170, window=button1)

def start_ruleset(): 
       subprocess.call([r'[path]\commands\ruleset.bat'])
           
button2 = tk.Button (root, text='nft flush ruleset',command=start_ruleset,)
canvas1.create_window(55, 17, window=button2)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The program you're launching apparently doesn't exit any time soon - perhaps it requires user input before it exits.  To avoid locking up your code, you'd need to launch it in a way that doesn't wait for the process to exit - `subprocess.Popen()` for example.

Comment: Thanks a lot for help, it solved my problem! :)